# How can I add user analytics to my SwiftUI app?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app that I need to add user analytics to, to track events like:

- how long a user spent on a specific page / how many times that page was visited
- how many times certain buttons were pressed
- when the app was opened / closed / for how long, etc.

Q1. What are the most common SwiftUI analytics frameworks?

Q2. How can I implement analytics frameworks into my SwiftUI app? It seems that many of the frameworks I've already seen have only Objective-C implementations (e.g. segment-io).

Answer (score 1):

I think Google Analytics can help you in the required scope.
Check: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3?ver=swift

Regarding its usage with SwiftUI, you'll use the corresponding lifecycle method to invoke the required analytics tracking, as the following

```
.onAppear {
        // [START screen_view_hit_swift]
        guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker else { return }
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: name)

        guard let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView() else { return }
        tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        // [END screen_view_hit_swift]
    }
```

As an equivalent to:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    // [START screen_view_hit_swift]
    guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker else { return }
    tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: name)

    guard let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView() else { return }
    tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    // [END screen_view_hit_swift]
```

}

Comment: Google Analytics was one of my thoughts, yet isn't it being shut down for mobile analytics?

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112?hl=en

Comment: It's shut down as a standalone analytics SDK, but it's become a built-in to Firebase SDK. Which I've mentioned above. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9165830